# Confused on Excel DATEDIF "YD" Option

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having trouble understanding the below results:

```
=DATEDIF(DATE(2003,9,29),DATE(2013,8,28),"YD")
```

returns 334

whereas

```
=DATEDIF(DATE(2012,9,29),DATE(2013,8,28),"D")
```

and

```
=DATE(2013,8,28)-DATE(2012,9,29)
```

returns 333 and is what I ultimately expect to get.

Why does the first formula return 334?

Thank you!

EDIT: Ultimately, what I want to achieve is to take in 2 dates and return the number of full years (so /365 doesn't work due to leap) + the remainder days to be divided by 365.

I thought of using

```
=DATEDIF(date1,date2,"Y")+DATEDIF(date1,date2,"YD")/365
```

but cases similar to the above throws it off. I could do a long-winded one, but was wondering about causes this.

Comment: You'll notice that =DATEDIF(DATE(2012,9,29),DATE(2013,8,28),"YD") returns 333. If you compare different dates, you get different results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
=DATEDIF(DATE(2003,9,29),DATE(2013,8,28),"y")+(DATE(2013,8,28)-EDATE(DATE(2003,9,29),12*DATEDIF(DATE(2003,9,29),DATE(2013,8,28),"y")))/365
```

Comment: I was just posting what I thought was a better solution!.....turns out it was the same as yours +1

Answer (score 0):

`Chip Pearson` explains why that happens [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datedif.aspx) - scroll down the page to near the end, under "DATEDIF And Leap Years"

I recommend **nutsch**'s solution to your problem but you might also want to look at `YEARFRAC` function to get fractional years - I don't seem to be able to get the exact same results as with nutsch's formula but this will give you something close

`=YEARFRAC(A2,B2,3)`

Comment: Yes, there are simpler formulas that yield really close results, but unfortunately I need this exact way of calculation. I was actually at Chip Pearson's page, but did not scroll all the way down; thanks for pointing it out!